# IDA RIP points to address that is not defined as code

Tags: assembly, windows-10, x86-64, ida

So ive been practicing my assembly lately and i ran into something a bit strange. i have this segment of code defined at the beginning of my main function.

```
            global  main
            SECTION .text
main:       xor     rcx, rcx
loop:       inc     rcx
            mov     r8, none
            mov     r9, none
first:      mov     rdx, 3
            call    mod
            cmp     eax, 0
            jnz     second
            mov     r8, fizz
```

the program compiles and runs just fine, but when i put it into IDA it seems to have trouble with the above segment. It parses out the single instruction of main perfectly fine, but when it gets to the "inc rcx" instruction within loop the instructions seem to fail to parse and the value "49C1FF48h" on line 401533 gets highlighted red

```
.text:0000000000401550                 public main
.text:0000000000401550 main:                                   ; CODE XREF: __tmainCRTStartup+242↑p
.text:0000000000401550                 xor     rcx, rcx
.text:0000000000401550 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:0000000000401553 ; stringop_alg loop
.text:0000000000401553 loop            dd 49C1FF48h            <--ISSUE IS HERE
.text:0000000000401557                 db 0B8h
.text:0000000000401558                 dq offset none
.text:0000000000401560                 dq 403010B949h
.text:0000000000401568                 db 2 dup(0)
.text:000000000040156A first           dw 3BAh, 0
.text:000000000040156E                 dw 0E800h
.text:0000000000401570                 dq 7500F88300000057h, 403011B8490Ah
.text:0000000000401580                 db 3 dup(0)
```

when it gets to the line during execution it pauses and IDA pops up a warning `IDA has detected that RIP points to an address which is not defined as code. Would you like to directly create an instruction at RIP ?`. after clicking yes ida seems to be able to shift things around and parse it correctly, but all of the addresses turn red.

this confuses me. as far as i can tell i haven't done anything that would cause a warning like this. im pretty inexperienced with assembly but could be an issue with alignment? thats all i can think of but it doesnt seem like im doing anything that would cause alignment issues. ive also tried adding in nops before the loop to align it and specifically jumping/calling loop from main to see if that would fix it but that didnt seem to change anything. part of me feels like this could be an issue on IDAs end, but i feel like i should exhaust more possibilities before blaming the tool im using.

compiled on windows 10 using: `nasm -fwin64 fizzbuzz.asm && gcc -m64 -mconsole fizzbuzz.obj -o fizzbuzz.exe`

heres the full program : https://pastebin.com/FwW5YSji

Comment: That's weird. Both my 6.6 and 7.0 versions of IDA have no problem disassembling your program when I assemble and link it (tested both golink and gcc). Can you share your binary somewhere? Looking at the code I don't see anything that should trouble IDA. What version of IDA are you using?

Comment: version 7.2. heres the binary
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xcGVUpFHOgkAjFY7SC-1-9gQ9c5GP3F0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: and in case you cant recreate it, heres exactly what it looks like on my end https://imgur.com/a/cjiD5o1

Comment: I can reproduce it. It seems to have to do with some DWARF (debug) symbol defined in the binary. If you don't load them (by clicking Cancel when presented with the relative dialog) IDA has no problem. If you load the DWARF symbols, you get a message, in the console output, about "stringalg_op: cannot failed to add constant loop=6 (0x6)". You can fix it by simply clicking on the first line of data and press "c" to make it into code. That should work for debugging too, but I don't know, I never debug with IDA.

Comment: ahh got it. yep that worked for me :) thanks so much!